There is a delay when saving data into a Room Database
I'm trying to create a stop watch application. Everything works fine at first. The stop watch goes up from the milliseconds, to the seconds, to the minutes just fine. There are two timers, one of the current time and one for the lap time. The problem comes when trying to add laps.
The laps are saved into Room so they'll stay there on recomposition. The current time and the lap time are retrieved and placed into an item into a lazy column. However, the first lap is empty and the time is around four seconds to early. For example, if you created a lap at seven seconds it would actually say three seconds.
Here is the Main Activity. There is an instance of the viewmodel and database at the top.  There are two sets of three variables representing the time. One set is for the current time, one set is for the lap time. The timers are triggered by booleans that start a launched effect. There is a button to start/stop, reset, and lap the timer. Underneath that is a lazy column that displays the laps.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val stopWatchDatabase by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            StopWatchDatabase::class.java,
            name = "object.database"
        ).build()
    }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<StopWatchViewModel> (
        factoryProducer =  {
            object: ViewModelProvider.Factory{
                override fun <T: ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T{
                    return StopWatchViewModel((stopWatchDatabase)) as T
                }
            }
        }
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {

            // Time
            var milliseconds by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
            var seconds by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
            var minutes by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

            // Lap Time
            var lapMilliseconds by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
            var lapSeconds by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
            var lapMinutes by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

            // Time Display
            var overallTime by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            var lapTime by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

            // Timer Active States
            var isTimerActive by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            var isLapTimerActive by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

            // Lap List
            var laps by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Lap>()) }

            // Instance Of Lap Entity
            val newLap = Lap(
                lapNumber = laps.size + 1,
                overallTime = overallTime,
                lapTime = lapTime
            )

            // Function To Retrieve Lap List
            viewModel.retrieveAllLaps().observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) {
                 laps = it
            }

            // Start Timer Launched Effect
            LaunchedEffect(isTimerActive) {
                while (isTimerActive && milliseconds < 100) {
                    delay(1)
                    milliseconds++
                    while (milliseconds == 100) {
                        seconds += 1
                        milliseconds = 0
                        while (seconds == 60) {
                            minutes += 1
                            seconds = 0
                            milliseconds = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Start Lap Timer Launched Effect
            LaunchedEffect(isTimerActive && isLapTimerActive) {
                while (isTimerActive && isLapTimerActive && lapMilliseconds < 100) {
                    delay(1)
                    lapMilliseconds++
                    while (lapMilliseconds == 100) {
                        lapSeconds += 1
                        lapMilliseconds = 0
                        while (lapSeconds == 60) {
                            lapMinutes += 1
                            lapSeconds = 0
                            lapMilliseconds = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // App Layout
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                // Time Display
                Text(
                    text = "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(minutes, seconds, milliseconds),
                    fontSize = 50.sp
                    )
                if (isLapTimerActive) {

                    // Lap Time Display
                     Text(
                     text = "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(lapMinutes, lapSeconds, lapMilliseconds),)
                }

                // Button To Start Timer
                Button(onClick = { isTimerActive = !isTimerActive }) {
                Text(text = "Start")
                }

                // Button To Reset Timer
                Button(onClick = {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        isTimerActive = false
                        isLapTimerActive = false
                        viewModel.deleteAllLaps()
                        delay(1)
                        milliseconds = 0
                        seconds = 0
                        minutes = 0
                        lapMilliseconds = 0
                        lapSeconds = 0
                        lapMinutes = 0
                        overallTime = ""
                        lapTime = ""
                    }}) {
                    Text(text = "Reset")
                }

                 // Button To Lap Timer
                Button(onClick = {
                    overallTime = "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
                    lapTime = "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(lapMinutes, lapSeconds, lapMilliseconds)
                    viewModel.insertLap(newLap)
                    lapMilliseconds = 0
                    lapSeconds = 0
                    lapMinutes = 0
                    isLapTimerActive = true
                 }) {
                    Text(text = "Lap")
                }

                // Lap List
                LazyColumn(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(30.dp)
                ) {
                    items(laps) { lap ->
                        Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(30.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = lap.lapNumber.toString())
                        Text(text = lap.lapTime)
                        Text(text = lap.overallTime)
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is Lap Entity
@Entity
data class Lap(

    val lapNumber: Int?,
    val overallTime: String,
    var lapTime: String,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
)

Here is the Stopwatch Dao
@Dao
interface StopWatchDao {
    @Upsert
    suspend fun insertLap(lap: Lap)

    @Query("DELETE FROM Lap")
    suspend fun deleteAllLaps()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Lap")
    fun retrieveAllLaps(): Flow<List<Lap>>
}

Here is the Stopwatch Database
@Database(
    entities = [Lap::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class StopWatchDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val stopWatchDao: StopWatchDao
}

And finally the Stopwatch ViewModel
class StopWatchViewModel(private val stopWatchDatabase: StopWatchDatabase): ViewModel() {

     fun insertLap(lap: Lap){
        viewModelScope.launch {
        stopWatchDatabase.stopWatchDao.insertLap(lap)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllLaps(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
        stopWatchDatabase.stopWatchDao.deleteAllLaps()
        }
    }

    fun retrieveAllLaps() = stopWatchDatabase.stopWatchDao.retrieveAllLaps().asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}

I tried placing the insertLap function into coroutine and adding a delay but that didn't work.
But away the problem is that the first lap in the lazy column is empty except for the lap number and the time on the rest is four seconds too early.
Thanks for your time reading my question.

I don't think it is worth trying to fix your current problem because your entire time measuring logic is faulty and must be replaced. Your watch isn't accurate and will never measure the time correctly. Just put a real stop watch next to yours and compare the elapsed time.
The problem is that you try to actively increase the elapsed time by a millisecond each millisecond. That won't work for two reasons:

After you wait for a millisecond you increase your elapsed time by a millisecond, but the code that does that takes some time too so after you wait another millisecond the actual time elapsed is strictly greater than a millisecond. How much exactly cannot be predicted, that depends on the hard- and software involved.
delay(1) only guarantees to wait at least one millisecond. There is no guarantee, however, that your code will continue exactly one millisecond later (it will probably not be far off in your case, though). That's in the nature of coroutines, it is a cooperative framework working on a best-effort basis, not a realtime framework that can provide hard guarantees. To make this reliably work you would actually need another kind of operating system, a Real-time operating system, which Android is not.

The only thing that is sufficiently reliable is the curremt time that the internal clock of the device provides. And that is also the solution: When the user starts the stop watch you just need to retrieve the current time. You can do that with
val startTime = Clock.System.now()

(Make sure you have the dependency org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime in your gradle files).
This time never changes, it represents the time when the watch was started. If you want to display the elapsed time, just retrieve the current time again and subtract the start time, it is really that simple:
val elapsed = Clock.System.now() - startTime

You get a Duration object representing the time that passed. Display this in your UI.
The only thing that you need to do in a LaunchedEffect is to regularly repeat measuring the elapsed time to update your UI. But do not do it each millisecond:

Even when you recompose your UI that often, the device's display will likely have a much lower framerate. Although you see some devices with a framerate of 120Hz or even higher, that is still far away from the 1000Hz you would need to actually display the recomposed state each millisecond.
The human eye is far from being able to resolve that many frames. Even if the hardware would be able to keep up, the user wouldn't benefit from it in the slightest.
The time displayed in your UI has only a digit for the hundredth second, updating the UI more often would result in the same output.

I probably wouldn't even update the UI each hundredth second though; try to find a sweet spot that looks nice but doesn't do unnecessary UI updates.
Now, when the "Lap" button is clicked you just need to measure the elapsed time again and save that somewhere. "Somewhere" doesn't mean in a database, though:

The laps are saved into Room so they'll stay there on recomposition.

Room is the wrong tool to prevent data being lost on recomposition. That's what remember is for. If you also want to save your data from being lost on device reconfigurations then you should use rememberSaveable or store the data in the view model. Only if you need your data to survice an app restart you need a database. Although a simple DataStore would probably suffice for this. But you do not even store the current time in the database, so storing just the lap times is pretty useless.

You will probably need to throw out most of your code, but the actual code you need to properly do this will be much shorter. The original problem from your question will most likely also be fixed along the way.

Does shortening the milliseconds variable to 100 or 10 before increasing the seconds variable help? I know most stopwatch only display milliseconds in a range of 1-10 or 1-100. I've never seen one reach 1000.

No, that approach is inherently flawed and cannot be fixed, see points 1 and 2. It must be replaced with what I proposed instead.
